# Could not open extension control file POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, foreign-data-wrapper, postgres-fdw

While trying to execute PostgreSQL extension in PostgreSQL 13

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

I am getting an error

> CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw "Could not open extension control file "/opt/pgsql13/share/extension/postgres_fdw.control": No such file or directory

Comment: Did you install the "contrib" package? e.g. `yum install postgresql13-contrib`

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the issue for tablefunc.control extension issue post installing the postgresql13-contrib package